# Swisscom Cloud DB Backup fails

Tags: swisscomdev

We are using a MariaDB and a MongoDB (single instance) service in the [Swisscom App Cloud](http://developer.swisscom.com/).

If i try to create a backup with the backup button, it starts to create one, but fails after a few minutes.
Also, if i try to delete the failed entry, the deletion fails as well.
The interface provides no further information about the reason.
This happens for MariaDB as well as for MongoDB.

What could be a possible reason and how am I able to debug this error? Where can I get further information about the error?

screenshot of Portal:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simon here from the App Cloud Team.
There was an issue in the backend which we fixed this morning, so your backups should now work again.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for the info Simon, you are right, it works again.

Answer (score 2):

I developed a [CF CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html) plugin for DB backups (MariaDB) in Cloud Foundry, called "[cf-mariadb-backup-plugin](https://github.com/gsmachado/cf-mariadb-backup-plugin)", that also works in the Swisscom App Cloud. Check it out [here](https://github.com/gsmachado/cf-mariadb-backup-plugin), and give it a star. ;-)

If you use such plugin it presents the error message catch directly from the Cloud Foundry API. This might provide you, at least, better reasons on why such actions are failing.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, I tried you tool and it worked like a charm on the first try.
Unfortunately, it does not display any error, wether the backup creation / deletion process fails or not. It always displays just OK.

Comment: `
$ cf create-mariadb-backup -s mariadb-dev
Creating a backup in org MyOrg / space Development of service mariadb-dev...
OK

$ cf list-mariadb-backups -s mariadb-dev
`

Comment: mhh, formatting was not working
`$ cf create-mariadb-backup -s mariadb-dev`
`Creating a backup in org MyOrg / space Development of service mariadb-dev...`
`OK`
`$ cf list-mariadb-backups -s mariadb-dev`

Comment: @kaktusgruen yeah, then, it's a problem in the Swisscom AppCloud itself, since they are not returning any error code, somehow. Otherwise the plugin would display the error message. So it seems that AppCloud is just returning "everything is fine", but, in fact, it's not. Strange.